# Create a program using NLTK that asks for a word and checks whether it is more frequent as a Noun or a Verb in Brown corpus

Tags: python, nlp, nltk, corpus, tagged-corpus

```
import nltk
from nltk.corpus import brown
user=input("Enter a word:")
words=brown.tagged_words()
for word in words:
    if
```

I have started like this but I can"t go on

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Answer (score 0):

Just a hint:

```
print(words[0:9])
```

will give you:

```
[('The', 'AT'), ('Fulton', 'NP-TL'), ('County', 'NN-TL'), ('Grand', 'JJ-TL'), ('Jury', 'NN-TL'), ('said', 'VBD'), ('Friday', 'NR'), ('an', 'AT'), ('investigation', 'NN')]
```

This is a list of tuples, where the first value is the word (token) and the second is the token type.

so you might say:

```
for word in words:
    if word[0] == user:
        # do something depending on the value of word[1]
```